# How to insert data from one table column to another table

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a file that is something like below format.

test.txt

1 | ABC | A, B, C, D

I need a stored procedure that insert record in details table in row by row basis. e.g.

```
ID   Name   Type
1    ABC    A
1    ABC    B
1    ABC    C
1    ABC    D
```

Is it possible through stored procedure in sql. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- Split it in your code and then insert them
- Bulk insert them in a temporary table and split them all like this:

  ```
  -- SAMPLE Data
  declare @data table(id int, name varchar(10), type varchar(100))
  insert into @data(id, name, type) values
  (1, 'ABCD', 'A, B, C, D')
  , (2, 'EFG', 'E, F, G')
  , (3, 'HI', 'H, I')

  -- Split All Rows and Types
  Select ID, Name, ltrim(rtrim(value))
  From (
      Select *,  Cast('<x>'+Replace(d.type,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' As XML) As types
      From @data d
  ) x
  Cross Apply (
      Select types.x.value('.', 'varchar(10)') as value
      From x.types.nodes('x') as types(x)
  ) c
  ```

Output:

```
    ID  Name    Type
    1   ABCD    A
    1   ABCD    B
    1   ABCD    C
    1   ABCD    D
    2   EFG     E
    2   EFG     F
    2   EFG     G
    3   HI      H
    3   HI      I
```